# How can I get user data using facebook php sdk?

Tags: php, facebook

I want to get user data using php sdk ..

```
$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$user_id = $facebook->getUser();
var_dump($user_id );
```

It returns me int(0) although I am logged in to facebook .Hiw can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

The user needs to be connected with your Facebook App. You need to request permissions from him to access the data. The Facebook SDK docs have everything you need to know about permissions etc.

Edit_:
Here's a sample on how to request permissions from the user (taken from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl/)

```
$params = array(
  'scope' => 'read_stream, friends_likes',
  'redirect_uri' => 'https://www.myapp.com/post_login_page'
);

$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
```

After getting the login URL, just redirect the user to this URL or use an `a` tag like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>">Login with Facebook</a>
```

Comment: STill does not work ..When I click on the link , it dies not do anything

Comment: When i click the button here is the error message "Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options."

Comment: So you're opening the URL in a Frame? Seems like Facebook does not allow the site being shown in an iFrame. Try it without an iFrame!